# Python - can't understand this reverse program

Tags: python, reverse

This is the code, the main goal of this program is to print the message backwards

```
message = 'Here is an example'
translated = ''
i = len(message) - 1
while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1
print(translated)
```

What I can't understand is the 3rd line, the message contains 18 characters but 'i' subtracts one so it's 17, when you run this program every symbol is there, the 5th line prints out the message with i (still 1 character less) and nothing is missing, can anyone explain why is everything there?I know that you can do it with only 2 lines like this

```
message = 'Here is an example'
print(message[::-1])
```

but I want to understand the longer program.

Comment: What's not to understand? Have you tried adding any `print`s to see how the values change?

Comment: +1 For giving code and pointing out exactly what was confusing you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indices in most languages start with 0, so the last character index will be the length - 1

Comment: I didn't know that applies here, I'm really disappointed that this wasn't explained in the book I'm currently reading, read 2 of the most recommended books and both of them fail to explain things like these, thank you for your (fast) answer, this program really made me think.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the 1-based to 0-based conundrum.

Lists in python (and most languages) are 0-based. We think in a 1-based fashion. In other words, we start counting from 1. But computers start counting from 0!

So, if we want to iterate through a list, we need to first subtract one from the length. A list that is of length 3 will have 3 elements in it, and their indexes will be 0 through 2. If we try and access something at index 3, we will get an index out of bounds exception.

Does that help?

Comment: I actually usually think in base 10, but I know what you mean. :P